# Who is the Marvel masked hero in the picture?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

[image]

We have this character that says "Marvel" on its back.
He looks like a black, masked hero, with an orange and silver suit.

Any idea who this is?

Comment: Any idea as to age of the figure ?  Could be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That has to be Power Man (Luke Cage)
http://comicsalliance.com/ultimate-spider-man-cartoon-luke-cage-power-man/

[image]

Here's the link from Marvel as well http://marvel.com/news/story/18207/spider-man_his_ultimate_friends_power_man
He dates back to the 70's, this is a new look

Comment: Great research job, darned if I could find it !  +1